# Array element naming when using cake/sql

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have a piece of code in cake where I am getting multiple rows of data back from SQL, and in one of the columns there is a numeric value I need to check and change the data to text if it equals a certain number. In order to do this I need to know how the array elements are named `$results[????]` in order to get this value and change it. So what are the naming conventions of arrays when using SQL/Cake?

Here is the caked code:

```
$params = array(
    'fields' => array(
        $this->name . '.AUTHORIZE_PROVIDER_NAME',           
        $this->name . '.SOURCE_ID',
        $this->name . '.ORDER_ITEM_TITLE',
        $this->name . '.DOSE_AMOUNT',      
        $this->name . '.DOSE_UNIT',
        $this->name . '.DT_CREATED_TIME',
        $this->name . '.ROUTE_ID',
        $this->name . '.SEQUENCE_NO',
        $this->name . '.LOCATION',
        $this->name . '.BODY_SITE_ID',
        $this->name . '.COMMENT', 
        'DD.DICTIONARY_DATA_CODE',
    ),

    /*
    'conditions' => array(
        //conditions
        $this->name . '.HID'    => $hospital_id,
        $this->name . '.PID'    => $patient_id,                
    ),
    */

    'order' => array(
        $this->name . '.DT_CREATED_TIME',
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table'     => 'DICTIONARY_DATA',
            'alias'     => 'DD',
            'type'      => 'INNER',
            'fields'    => 'DD.DICTIONARY_DATA_CODE as DD_Code',
            'conditions'=> array(
                $this->name . '.PRIORITY_ID = DD.DICTIONARY_DATA_ID',
                $this->name . '.HID' => $hospital_id,
                $this->name . '.PID' => $patient_id,
            )
        )
    ),
);
$rs = $this->find('all', $params);
```

And I am getting the data here:

```
foreach ($rs as $record){
    try {
        $result[] = $record[$this->name];
        array_push($result, $record['DD']);
    }
}
```

And returning it to be printed out as a JSON object. So I want to get into `$results[]` to check the numeric value of `SOURCE_ID` and `ROUTE_ID`. How can I do this without doing a `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

When using caking SQL statements, the a 3-D array is given back (2-D when only one field, or select, is requested). They are named as such:

```
Array(
    Array[table_name] =>
        [column_name] => field value
        [column_name] => field value
        .
        .
    Array[table_name] =>
        [column_name] => field value
        [column_name] => field value
        .
        .
    .
    .
);
```

And when each is run through a foreach statement, the element changes to a number `[table_name]`  or `[column_name]` is now `[0]`, or `[1]`, etc. depending on where it is in the array.

In order to check the numeric values of `ROUTE_ID` and `SOURCE_ID` I created a hash table as such

```
$sourceValues = array(
        500002 => 'Verbal',
        500003 => 'Telephone',
        500004 => 'Written',
        500005 => 'Other'
    );

$routeValues = array(
        11     => 'Intramuscular',
        22     => 'Nasal',
        28     => 'Subcutaneous'
    );
```

and ran through the values of each row of `SOURCE_ID` and `ROUTE_ID` as such:

```
foreach($record as $value){
           $source = $value['SOURCE_ID'];
           $route = $value['ROUTE_ID'];
           $value['SOURCE_ID'] = $sourceValues[$source];
           $value['ROUTE_ID'] = $routeValues[$route];
           $result[] = $value;
    }
```